# Generalized Eigenvalue Problem - How to solve? Fisherfaces

Tags: optimization, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, discriminant, generalized-eigenvector

I'm trying to do picture recognition. There are 3 types of methods from OpenCV library. Eigenfaces, Fisherfaces and Local Binary Pattern Histogram. These are good, but in practice, Fisherfaces is the best becase Eigenfaces is good if you have a noisy picture and Local Binary Pattern Histogram cannot handle noice, but it can handle linear illumination differences.

And Ficherfaces can handle both.

To do Fisherfaces we need to have a collection $X$ where $X$ contains vector $c$ classes of pictures.

This is our collection of pictures in form of vectors:
 $$X = X_1, X_2, X_3, ... , X_c$$

This is our picture in form of a vector:
 $$X_i = x_1, x_2, x_3, ... , x_n$$

Then we need to create scatter matrices.

Here $N_i$ is the index of the vector $x_n$
$$S_B = \sum_{i=1}^c N_i(\mu_i  - \mu)(\mu_i - \mu)^T$$

$$S_W = \sum_{i=1}^c\sum_{x_j \in X_i}(x_j  - \mu_i)(x_j - \mu_i)^T$$

We can find the means from:
$$\mu = \frac{1}{N} \sum_{i=1}^N x_i$$
And this is just the mean of a single class $X_i$
$$\mu_i = \frac{1}{|N_i|}\sum_{x_j \in X_i} X_j$$

Now to my question:
How can I solve this opitmization problem?

Wet want to maximize this matrix $W_{opt}$. This is the criteria.

$$W_{opt} = arg max_w \frac{|W^TS_BW|}{|W^TS_WW|}$$

We can solve this optimization problem by solving the generalized eigenvalue problem: $det(A - \lambda I) = 0$:

$$S_W^{-1}S_B V_i = \lambda_i V_i$$

Or if $S_W$ is singular, we can add a small constant $\epsilon$ so $S_W$ can be invertable. That is recommended.
$$ (S_W +\epsilon I)^{-1}S_B V_i = \lambda_i V_i$$

Or we can skip the $\epsilon$ and find $S_W^{-1}$ by using House Holder QR-factorization or Singular Value Decomposition. It can handle singular matrices.

The optimization problem can be described as:

$$W_{PCA} = argmax_W |W^TS_TW|$$
$$W_{FLD} = argmax_W \frac{W^TW^T_{PCA}S_BW_{PCA}W}{W^TW^T_{PCA}S_WW_{PCA}W}$$
$$W = W^T_{FLD} W^T_{PCA}$$

Copy from the lecture notes [here](https://www.slideshare.net/VishnuKN1/fisherfaces-face-recognition-algorithm) and [here](http://cs.haifa.ac.il/~dkeren/ip/eigen-fischer-faces.pdf) and [here](https://cseweb.ucsd.edu/classes/wi14/cse152-a/fisherface-pami97.pdf). This is the best lecture [note](http://courses.cs.tamu.edu/rgutier/csce666_f13/l10.pdf).

**Questions:**

How can I use generalized eigenvalue problem to solve this optimization problem?

Should I first set $W = I$ and then compute $W_{PCA} = argmax_W |W^TS_TW|$ ? Then the following equation $W_{FLD} = argmax_W \frac{W^TW^T_{PCA}S_BW_{PCA}W}{W^TW^T_{PCA}S_WW_{PCA}W}$ and last this equation: $W = W^T_{FLD} W^T_{PCA}$

Then compare it with 
$$W_{opt} = arg max_w \frac{|W^TS_BW|}{|W^TS_WW|}$$

And check how large $W_{opt}$ is? The largest $W_{opt}$ is the solution?

**Edit:**

Or does it mean like $W = V_1, V_2, V_2, ... , V_i$ is the collection of eigen-vectors?

All I need to do is to:

1. Find your $\mu_i$ and $\mu$ and also $S_w$ and $S_b$
2. Solve the generalized eigenvalue problem

$$S_W^{-1}S_B V_i = \lambda_i V_i$$

3. Check how large $W_{opt}$? If not largest? Try next sample.

$$W_{opt} = arg max_w \frac{|W^TS_BW|}{|W^TS_WW|}$$